# What does file_put_contents set as permissions?

Tags: php

It sounds perhaps hackish but if I use file_put_contents to write a .php file, what permissions does the file get? I couldn't find any documentation regarding what permissions `file_put_contents` sets. (Assuming the file did not exists before).

In this case this file is **not** written from any user input or even from the web at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents php permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479315/file-put-contents-php-permissions)

Comment: No function itself decides upon the file system permissions granted for a file created by them, directly or indirectly. That is done by the underlying operating system or the shell environment. Take a look at the user account and group membership of the process the script is executed under and the `umask` set for the process which filters potential permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would typically be 644 for a user.

But it can depend on the application setting that called the function.  You can modify the default creation permissions for `httpd` and lot's of other applications.

You said, it's not from any user input or the web.  But however it's called, there will be an associated user.